# Difference between two date columns formatted as General

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have two columns in Excel, formatted as General - with this data:

```
Column A                    Column B   
11/2/2014 9:12:27 AM        12/3/2014 2:00:00 AM
```

How can I find the difference in hours between them, if they are formatted as "General" and not "Date"?

Thank you for any advice,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that means these are actually text formatted *datetimes* - you can test by trying to change the format, e.g. try to change to "Number" - if nothing changes theses are text values.

You can still subtract, though, if the *datetimes* are in a valid format for your region.

Try using a simple subtraction like

`=B1-A1`

custom format result cell as **[h]:mm**

I get the result **688:47** (which assumes that the first timestamp is 11th Feb not 2nd November)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=VALUE(B1)-VALUE(A1)
```

custom formatted as`[HH]`.

Comment: I don't think using VALUE will make any difference - `=B1-A1` should be sufficient because the subtraction will force a co-ercion

Comment: I'm not sure about that, like worksheet function TRIM? If I format as text and put extra spaces between date and time then both formulas work for me